# element.sendkey not sending the space key

Tags: angularjs, protractor

So the basic problem is I have an protractor test that is failing because the space is missing. If I send "new title" it puts "newtitle" in the field, causing it to fail.

Example code:

```
it('should allow the description to be editted', function () {
    element.all(by.css('h4.review__header__item')).then(function (headerItems) {
        var description = headerItems[1];
        expect(description.getText()).toEqual('Short Test Meeting');
        browser.actions().mouseMove(description).click(description).perform();
        expect(description.getAttribute('contenteditable')).toBeTruthy();
        description.clear().sendKeys('Description New').sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER);
        element.all(by.css('h4.review__header__item')).then(function (headerItems) {
            description = headerItems[1];
            expect(description.getText()).toEqual('Description New');

            // Check to see if it persists
            browser.refresh();
            element.all(by.css('h4.review__header__item')).then(function (headerItems) {
                description = headerItems[1];
                expect(description.getText()).toEqual('Description New');
            });
        });
    });
});
```

The Error:

1) Review Meeting Meta Data should allow the description to be editted

Message:

Expected 'DescriptionNew' to equal 'Description New'.

Stack:
    Error: Failed expectation
        at /Users/adam/git/mrp-www/e2e/scenarios/reviewScenario.js:18:36
        at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (/Users/adam/git/mrp-www/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1379:14)
        at TaskQueue.execute_ (/Users/adam/git/mrp-www/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2913:14)
        at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (/Users/adam/git/mrp-www/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2896:21)
        at asyncRun (/Users/adam/git/mrp-www/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2775:27)
        at /Users/adam/git/mrp-www/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:639:7
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)

Comment: BTW: I manually verified that typing into the description field works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're missing a *.perform()* after *sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER)*.

Try this:

```
description.clear().sendKeys('Description New').sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER).perform();
```

Comment: Nope, perform is not a function of element. test failed.

Comment: Try to split this up.

Comment: Try to split this up:

description.clear();
description.sendKeys('Description New');

Comment: Try to split this up:

description.clear(); 
description.sendKeys('Description New');
browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER).perform();

Comment: Same failure as above.  Expected 'DescriptionNew' to equal 'Description New'.